# UIAlertView subclass with text fields for iOS 4

Tags: iphone, uialertview

Has anyone seen a solution for adding text fields to a UIAlertView (without private APIs)? On 3.x I've been using enormego's EGOTextFieldAlertView, but this doesn't work properly when compiled for iOS 4. Any suggestions?
http://github.com/enormego/EGOTextFieldAlertView/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a viable solution:
Use the ModalAlert from Erica Sadun's cookbook.
http://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C10-Alerts/03-Soliciting%20Text/

Answer (score 2):

The solution described [here](http://www.iostipsandtricks.com/using-uialertview-as-a-text-prompt/) works great for me.

Answer (score 1):

Jose Castillo found a fix for EGOTextFieldAlertView in iOS 4 and can be found here:
https://github.com/josecastillo/EGOTextFieldAlertView

It has a bit of a problem with auto-positioning the view, but there are several easy fixes, depending on your project needs.

I highly recommend this code as a start point.

Comment: Looks like this code stopped working on iOS 4.3 .... Has anyone found the definitive solution?